# Overhead of std::vector of size 1 compared to simple type

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have several classes that capture are certain functionality and have a simply type member variable, e.g.

```
float m_a;
```

For all of these classes, I need now an additional version where this member is a nested vector of a such a simple type, e.g.

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> m_a;
```

Size of the vectors is not known during compile time but constant during object lifetime. The remaining functionality stays the same, only that every access to m_a in the first case is replaced by a corresponding nested for-loop in the second case.

Obviously, the second case contains the first case as a special case by using vectors of size 1 (only m_a[0][0]).

This would save me writing several new classes with nearly identical behavior. However, objects of these classes are used (created and accessed) thousands to millions of times. So the question is, how critical is the memory and access overhead created by that?

Edit: I tried to test it with the following simplified program.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class A{
    public:
    A(float a) : m_a(a) {}; 
    float m_a;
};
class B{
    public:
    B(float b) : m_b({b}) {};
    std::vector<float> m_b;
};
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    unsigned numOfRuns = 10;              // to average out random fluctuations
    for(int r = 0; r < numOfRuns; r++){
        unsigned n = atoi(argv[1]);

        std::vector<A> a;   // simple type
        a.reserve(n);
        clock_t ta1 = clock();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            a.emplace_back( A(i) );  // create
        }
        clock_t ta2 = clock();

        std::vector<B> b;  // 1-element array
        b.reserve(n);
        clock_t tb1 = clock();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            b.emplace_back( B(i) );    // create
        }
        clock_t tb2 = clock();

        clock_t ta3 = clock();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            a[i].m_a;            // access
        }
        clock_t ta4 = clock();

        clock_t tb3 = clock();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            b[i].m_b[0];        // access
        }
        clock_t tb4 = clock();

        std::cout << n << "\t" << ((tb2-tb1)/(float)(ta2-ta1)) << "\t" << ((tb4-tb3)/(float)(ta4-ta3)) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

According to this, creation takes 13x more time and access 1.8x more. I also checked briefly the memory consumption, which was nearly a factor of 10 larger for n=10000000.

Unless I made some stupid mistake, this is really surprising for me. I expected some overhead but not an order of magnitude more memory and time consumption.

Comment: Is `m_a` is always a rectangular table (inner rows of equal length) you can easily use `std::vector<float> m_a;` instead. It would reduce memory overhead and the number of indirections by half. Associate each element to a coordinate using a simple transformation like `x + y*width`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you. Yes, that would certainly have speed up regarding the nested vector. However, it doesnt answer the actual question which is how it a vector of size 1 compares to the direct use of the type.

Comment: Look at `sizeof(std::vector<float>)` on your system. That is the minimum memory overhead for using `std::vector<float>`. You can compare it with `sizeof(float)` to get a minimum ratio. On my system I get `std::vector`'s size as 24 and `float` as 4. So it takes at least 9x more memory (`sizeof(std::vector<float> + sizeof(float) / sizeof(float) == 9` for me ) to use an `std::vector<float>(1)` instead of a single `float`. As for access performance, it can vary a lot, but an extra indirection can sometimes be very costly. All of this can change a lot from system to system and use case to use case.

Comment: That confirms the small experiment I did (see the edited post). Thanks. So seems like its a bad idea and I should go for writing new classes.